# Showing that $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y_i})(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y}) = 0$ for the generalized linear model

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model, linear, sums-of-squares

**Exercise :**

> Prove that for the generalized linear model, it is :
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y_i})(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y}) = 0$$

**Question :** How would one proceed with proving that for the generalized linear model ? I can prove it for the simple linear model but I seem to be stuck a bit for the generalized case.

Comment: Work on $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y_i})(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y}) = (Y-\hat Y)'(\hat Y - \bar Y)$.

Comment: @a_statistician If $ Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ then $\bar{Y} = \bar{X}\beta + \epsilon$ and $\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon}$ and then it is : $$(Y-\hat Y)'(\hat Y - \bar Y) = (X\beta + \epsilon - X\hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon})'(X\hat{\beta} + \hat{\epsilon}- \bar{X}\beta + \epsilon)$$ Now, what ?

Comment: Generalized linear model can be ambiguous. What type of generalized linear model are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linear model, $Y=X\beta +\epsilon$, $\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ and $\hat Y = X\hat \beta = X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$

$\sum_{i=1}(y_i−\hat y_i)(\hat y_i−\bar y)=(Y−\hat Y)′(\hat Y−\bar Y) = Y'(I-H)(H-\frac 1 n J)Y = Y'(I-H)HY - Y(I-H)\frac 1 n JY $

where $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ , and $J$ is matrix with elements 1.

$Y'(I-H)HY = Y'(H-HH)Y =0$

$Y'(I-H)\frac 1 n JY = Y'(I-H) \bar Y = \bar Y \sum_{i=1}(y_i−\hat y_i) = 0$

So $\sum_{i=1}(y_i−\hat y_i)(\hat y_i−\bar y) = 0$

Comment: Isn't the H matrix that you use for OLS instead of GLM?

Comment: $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. I do not know it belongs to OLS or GLM or both. I think this conclusion just correct for general linear model.

Comment: The conclusion might be correct but the $H$ that you use is the perpendicular [projection matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) (shortest distance) which associates to least squares and Gaussian error distribution. It is *not* in general related to generalized linear models.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Then how should be the correct approach ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\hat{y_i})(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y}) =  \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y}) 
 = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \hat{y_i}}_{\text{ equals zero if } \epsilon \perp \hat{y} } &-& \bar{y_i}\underbrace{  \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i}_{  \text{equals zero} } 
\end{array}$$

I do not believe that you have $\epsilon \perp \hat{y}$ for GLM, this is only the case if you have the residual vector represent the shortest distance between $y$ and the solution space of all possible $\hat{y}$, which is the least squares solution and relates to the assumption of Gaussian distributed errors.

Neither is $ \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i = 0 $ general. This means $\epsilon$ is perpendicular to the intercept term. Even in the case of a simple linear model this may not be true (simple linear regression without the intercept term).

---

(Computational) counter-examples:

```r
> # some data
> x <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
> y <- c(1.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.0)
> 
> # OLS (minimize squared errors)
> hat_y <- predict(lm(y~x))
> sum((y-hat_y)*(hat_y-mean(y)))
[1] 6.366435e-16
> 
> # GLM (using Gamma)
> hat_y <- predict(glm(y~x, family = Gamma(link="identity")),type="response")
> sum((y-hat_y)*(hat_y-mean(y)))
[1] -0.1042444
> 
> # GLM (using Gaussian but different link)
> hat_y <- predict(glm(y~x, family = gaussian(link="log")),type="response")
> sum((y-hat_y)*(hat_y-mean(y)))
[1] 0.1504989
>
> # OLS without intercept term
> hat_y <- predict(lm(y~0+x))
> sum((y-hat_y)*(hat_y-mean(y)))
[1] -0.26
```

Comment: Interesting and indeed true. I assume the exercise wants us to work under the assumption of Gaussian distributed errors regarding a fitted generalized model, but that isn't mentioned, so I guess your statement is perfect !

Comment: Even if you consider only the link function :

$$Y = g(X\beta) + \epsilon$$ 

with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, I do not think it works here as well.